# Migrate LG QuickMemo+ notes to ColorNote/Google Keep

Tags: lg, data-transfer, notes

I bought a new phone and it didn't have any note app aside from Google Keep. I mess around with Google Keep and didn't find any import option so I try ColorNote.

Then from my old LG phone, I tried to share the memo, but the format is `.lqm`. When I force them to open with ColorNote or WPS Office, it broke, and only random symbols and jumbled words remained. The share option didn't have a share as picture/PDF/text, just share as `.lqm`.

Is there a way to migrate this? Would be nice if I can use Google Keep, but ColorNote is ok too.

Comment: Far from a full solution, but I found [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xC10SUKxcI) at least explaining a [QuickMemo-lqm-to-txt-File-Converter](https://github.com/powerpoint45/QuickMemo-lqm-to-txt-File-Converter) tool to convert .lqm files into .txt files.

Comment: That works, but sadly I can't import it to ColorNote or GKeep. But I can use Evernote so I think that's ok